# Uploading a file with httpservlet to java.io.tmpdir through part.write - to an absolute tmp path

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, file-upload

I am trying to make a servlet to upload a file to a temporary location. When I build the file path everything seems alright.

> String uploadFilePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR;

and I get the absolute path: C:\Users\victor\AppData\Local\Temp\uploads

but when I call

> part.write(uploadFilePath + File.separator + fileName);

I get:
C:\Users\victor\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain\generated\jsp\pcpweb\ **C:\Users\victor\AppData\Local\Temp\uploads**

and an java.io.FileNotFoundException afterwards, far enough I guess.

So "write" is completing my path. I there a way to avoid this?
Thanks.

Using: glassfish and netbeans

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
    String uploadFilePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR;

    // creates the save directory if it does not exists
    File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
    }
    System.out.println("Upload File Directory=" + fileSaveDir.getAbsolutePath());

    String fileName = null;
    //Get all the parts from request and write it to the file on server
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        fileName = getFileName(part);
        part.write(uploadFilePath + File.separator + fileName);
    }

    request.setAttribute("message", fileName + " File uploaded successfully!");
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("gerencia.jsp").forward(
            request, response);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `@MultipartConfig` annotation in your servlet or a `multipart-config` section in your web.xml? If you do, please show them.

Comment: just @MultipartConfig, without any change

Comment: @WebServlet(name = "FileUploadServlet", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc for `Part.write()` mentions that:

> The file is created relative to the location as specified in the
>   MultipartConfig

My understanding is that for Glassfish, if you don't specify the location, it defaults to the value of:

```
getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir")
```

Which is probably the extra path that you see.

Try specifying the location in the `@MultipartConfig` annotation, e.g.:

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/somepath")
```

You could set the location to the value of the temp dir, and then just pass the bare filename to the `write()` method.

Comment: I will test and I post here again. but I have one question though, is there a way to pass an absolute path at run-time? it seems it need to be hard-coded and using something like System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") is not an option.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14044793/1464763. The short answer seems to be no.

Comment: this seems to work, at leat I dont hae the exception any more. but do I get the location at runtime to process the file.

Comment: You can use the `getInputStream()` method of the Part object to process the file. Or you could try to retrieve the context attribute mentioned in my answer.